# Calculate average, add date, and save query to a new table

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, subquery, average

I have a table named pt_products with the fields:

```
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ean` bigint(13) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `merchant` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2)NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Example of entries on the table:

```
INSERT INTO `pt_products` (`id`, `ean`, `merchant`, `price`) VALUES
 ('1', '884116311874', 'Amazon', '10000.00'),
  ('2', '884116311874', 'BestBuy', '10999.00'),
('3','884116321378', 'CyberPuerta', '14789.00'),
 ('4', '884116311875', 'Amazon', '10999.00'),
  ('5', '884116311875', 'BestBuy', '10000.00');
```

I want to create a new table called 'graph' from the data that is already on pt_products having those fields:

-ean code.
-average of the 'price' field of every entry that shares the same 'ean'
-Date when the entry was added to the new table, added automatically.

What I have tried [(demo)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=670a556331e99d90b836e734bb031807):

```
SELECT AVG(price)
FROM pt_products
GROUP BY ean;
```

And I get:

```
AVG(price)
929.500000
3697.333333
3834.000000
9999.990000
10499.500000
10499.500000
14789.000000
```

With that I get the average price of the entries that share the same ean, but I can't see the 'ean' corresponding to the average. And of course I'm not storing it to a new table, including the date when the query was launched.

The purpose of this is to get price average for every ean and every day, in order to make a graph from the data showing price as function of time, so I need retrieval date of the average.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `ean` column to the `select` clause:

```
select ean, avg(price) avg_price
from pt_products
group by ean
```

You can create a new table directly from the results of the query:

```
create table graph as
select ean, avg(price) avg_price, now() created_at
from pt_products
group by ean
```

But this does not let you fine-tune the table options (primary key, indexes, ...). It would be better to first create the table, then `insert` into it - and you can set up a timestamp that defaults to the current point in time:

```
create table graph (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    ean bigint(13) unsigned not null,
    avg_price decimal(10,2) not null,
    created_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);

insert into graph(ean, avg_price)
select ean, avg(price) avg_price
from pt_products
group by ean;
```

Comment: @LaheyCorey: the timestamp is automatically set to the datetime when the records are inserted (that's what the `default current_timestamp` does).

Comment: On the example creating first the table, what table is: "pt_products_agg" ? Should not that be "graph"?

Comment: @LaheyCorey: that's a typo. I started by calling this table `pt_products_agg`, then I noticed that you called it `graph`, and I changed it (but I missed one occurence...).

Comment: Alright. The problem I see with adding the timestamp when creating the table, is that everytime I add new values, the "created_at" colum from the "graph" table is updated to the date of the latest added values. So, I don't know which values where inseted at different times. All values have the same time and date.

Take a look here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9a4c889e07b1e4ebf904f026970c153a

Comment: @LaheyCorey: that's because all the queries in the fiddlde execute at the same second (so they all get the same timestamp). But in your actual use case, you will run this query periodically - so the timestamps won't be the same.